# Change default order column with checkbox - datatable js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

Is there a way of changing the sort column in datatable by checking a checkbox ?
When I click a "search button" to get data from database, I want the sort to be whatever the checkboxes as checked, like 1 and 3 or only 2 or only 3 and so on.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfhM.png)

when i check the box "Nome do Paciente", i want the column "Nome do Paciente" to be the deafult sort for that search.

Comment: Can you post some code. So that its easy to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i added an image, don't know if it helps

Comment: gonna try to add code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation OrderBy Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

The OrderBy Filter can have a collection with the names of columns that you want to order. When you change some check, you can add or remove an element on this array from your controller.

Remmember use this variable in your template. Like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:variableOrderBy">
</tr>
```

The variable `variableOrderBy` has the collection of columns.